# Flutter, order of calling build functions in app

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm new to flutter and I need some help.
I want to change the dimensional characteristics based on the position of the screen and its size, for which I use a separate SizeConfig class, which I initialize BEFORE the MaterialApp assembly.

Like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return OrientationBuilder(
            builder: (context, orientation) {
              
              // This is where I get the screen parameters
              SizeConfig().init(constraints, orientation);

              return MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                title: 'My Test App',
                theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
                home: SplashScreen(),
              );
            }
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

This works great, but only for the first time.
In my case, I use bottomNavigationBar and navigate through the tabs. Thus, the general structure of the project is as follows:

1. ->main()
2. main()->SplashScreen()
3. main()->SplashScreen()->mainMenu()
4. main()->SplashScreen()->mainMenu()->tabs()

When I am on a tab, when I flip the screen, I get a dimensional change after the app build has occurred. Thus, if I rebuild the screen, then I first call the OLD screen parameters, build the widget based on them, and then update the screen parameters.

This is how my application log looks like:

```
// This is where the screen widget is rebuilt
I/flutter (21574): FONT SIZE 12.342857142857145
// And only now the function for updating the screen and orientation
I/flutter (21574): call init
I/flutter (21574): portrait
I/flutter (21574): WIDTH: 411.42857142857144
I/flutter (21574): HEIGHT: 683.4285714285714
I/flutter (21574): HEIGHT MULTI 6.8342857142857145
I/flutter (21574): WIDTH MULTI 4.114285714285715
I/flutter (21574): imageSizeMultiplier 4.114285714285715
I/flutter (21574): textMultiplier 6.8342857142857145
I/flutter (21574): FONT SIZE 20.502857142857145
```

I don't understand how to do the opposite to build the widget on the new parameters. I understand that I can in theory call the recalculation of parameters in each widget, but it seems to me redundant. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

And one more question, what is the order of calling the application assembly? I was pretty sure that I would call the main build method first and then dive into the others and build them. But if this were the case, would I first update the data and then build the widget?

Answer (score 0):

The way I deal with different screen sizes is:

create sizeconfig class

```
class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}
```

initialize the variables by calling the init function.

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _homeScaffoldkey = new GlobalKey();
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold();
```

then use it like:

```
width:SizeConfig.screenWidth,
```

use the screenWidth and screenHeight properties to set sizes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using it now, just a slightly different option